# Сохранение из формы в файл + Робокасса

Tags: php, html

Всем добрый день.

Есть форма с большим количеством полей. Принцип ее работы:
1. Человек заполняет все поля.
2. Жмет кнопку "Продолжить".
3. Переходит на страницу, где выводится введенная им информация.
4. Под этим блоком стоит кнопка Робокассы "Оплатить", по которой он переходит к оплате.

**Задача:**
Надо, чтобы человек заполнил поля, перешел на post.php, оттуда, по кнопке "Оплатить" перешел на Робокассу, оплатил сумму. И ТОЛЬКО ПОСЛЕ ОПЛАТЫ информация из заполненной формы записалась в файл. Есть ли такая возможность? И если несложно, покажите пример в виде скрипта.

В данный момент получается только:
1. Человек жмет кнопку "Продолжить", переходит на страницу post.php;
2. Данные из формы записываются в файл, выводится страница с блоком введенной им информации и кнопкой "Оплатить", и только потом переходит к оплате.

P.S. После оплаты создается файл, информация из которого сразу выводится на сайте + отправляется на почту. Потому важно, чтобы запись в файл шла ПОСЛЕ оплаты.

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

**Обновление**

Форма отправляется в post.php. Код, который записывает данные формы в файл:

```
$project=$_POST['option'];
$myfname='Фамилия: '. $_POST['myfname'];
...

$rand=date("d.m.Y-G.i.s");
$handle = fopen("zayavka_$rand.txt", "w+");
foreach($project as $option)
{
$opt .=$option."\r\n";
}

fwrite($handle, iconv("UTF-8", "KOI8-R", "$opt\r\n"));
fwrite($handle, iconv("UTF-8", "KOI8-R", "$myfname\r\n"));
...

$URL="ok.html";
header ("Location: $URL");

fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Робокассы есть параметр ResultURL, который предназначен для получения Вашим сайтом оповещения об успешном платеже. Можете использовать его.

https://www.robokassa.ru/ru/Doc/Ru/Interface.aspx#Opoveshenie

Comment: Про это я в курсе. Но у них ограничение на суммарное кол-во знаков в 2048. А моя форма, как я сказал, большая. И всю форму тегом $shp не протащить.

Comment: Всю форму туда размещать нет смысла. В каком виде Вы записываете данные из формы в файл?

Comment: Добавляете в файл ещё параметр: флаг оплаты (0 или 1). По умолчанию 0. Далее используйте при отправке запроса к Робокассе "дополнительные параметры" и указывайте в них имя файла. А потом при получении запроса на ResultURL меняете эту строку с флагом оплаты.

https://www.robokassa.ru/ru/Doc/Ru/Interface.aspx#dop_par

Comment: Суть я понял, но не пойму, как реализовать. Вас не затруднит привести пример?

Comment: А как Вы отправляете запрос на сервер Робокассы? Вот создаёте перед отправкой запроса файл с полями, а в запрос включаете параметр shp_file (к примеру) с именем созданного файла. Потом получаете этот параметр скриптом, открываете этот файл и правите строку с флагом оплаты.

Comment: Этот вариант не подходит. Моя вина, не подумал уточнить:  
После оплаты создается файл, информация из которого сразу выводится на сайте + отправляется на почту.  
Как вставить параметр в код Робокассы я знаю. Просто не знаю, как это реализовать в моем скрипте.